# Does google datastore distinguish Entity from different users of he same application

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

If I have an application where many users try to upload entities of the same Kind with the same Id, will the GAE somehow distinguish and restrict access and uploads based on user ? if so can anyone explain or post a link to the details of how it's implemented

Comment: There is nothing intrinsically linked between the datastore entities and a user.  There are mechanism's you can use to potentially make things easier like namespaces, but the specifics are very much driven by your use case.  I suggest you do more research and develop your requirements further, and come back with a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine knows nothing about your users - your application code controls the entities and their ids.

You have two approaches to consider:

A. Use [Namespaces](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy).

B. Design your data model to have an entity "User" (or "Account", or "Customer" - whatever suits your needs), and then either make other entities child entities of a User entity (this approach has major limitations - [read about them first](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Ancestor_paths)), or simply reference the User entity in all entities that are related.

Answer (score 0):

A client is normally never in charge of defining ids for your new entities (there are very specific exceptions but that's most likely not the case).

Note that your database has to be the identifying master, and the only one in charge of assigning identity as you can't assure the process to be atomic out of its bounds. Alternatively you could ask your api to allocate a set of ids that you can safely use on your clients, but then again, it's likely that you don't need to get that far.

Some resources.
If you are using DataStore
[A DataStore write](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write)
[Id allocation on GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions)